# How to get output for a process running under another user?

Tags: linux, process

I have a long running process that a lab member started, but left for vacation. How can I view the output of the process on their machine? I have sudo access if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Found a good solution, this hooks into any syscalls that output to stdout.

```
sudo strace -p $(pgrep $MYPROCESS) -f -e write
```

Explanation:

- `-p` selects a PID
- `-f` follows any child processes spawned by the parent
- `-e` filters for the `write` syscall